# If Not Empty PHP WordPress Syntax Causing Critical Error

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

Can someone please help me fix this PHP code?

```
<?php
$ori = the_terms('origin');
if (!empty($ori)):
    ?>
    <div class="tax"><p class="origin tax-label">Origin</p><p class="tax-link tax-label"><?php the_terms( $post->ID, 'origin', '' ); ?></p></div>
<?php
   endif;
?>
```

It saves without any errors in the PHP file through the WordPress dashboard but shows "There has been a critical error on this website." on the front end.

I'm trying to display a custom taxonomy "origin" on the front-end, but only if it's not empty.

Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please consult your server's PHP error log for details about the actual error.

Comment: More context would be helpful to understand the problem. Which file is saved with the above content. What are you trying to achieve? Can you provide a _minimal_ error reproduction example?

Comment: @IngoSteinke I've updated the post and added more context.

Comment: @heyitsritesh in the WP reference, the_terms has no signature with just 1 parameter like `the_terms('origin')`, see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_terms/